# How convert CamelCase string to separate words?

Tags: string-manipulation

Is there some simpler way than the one below to convert a CamelCased string to a string consisting of separate words?

A crude way, with tedious typing, is the following:

```
unCamelCase[str_] := 
 StringDrop[
  StringJoin[
   StringSplit[
    str, {"A" -> " a", "B" -> " b", "C" -> " c", "H" -> " h", 
     "I" -> " i", "O" -> " o", "S" -> " s", "Z" -> " z"}]], 1]
```

(In the above I omitted from the list of replacements in `StringSplit` the letters I don't need for the particular example below, but for the method being used, in general I'd need the list of all 26 replacements.)

For example:

```
   unCamelCase["CompactSubspaceOfHausdorffSpaceIsClosed"]
(* compact subspace of hausdorff space is closed *)
```

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1902749)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two resource functions: [`FromCamelCase`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FromCamelCase) and [`ToCamelCase`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ToCamelCase). `FromCamelCase` splits camel case phrases into words. Add `ToLowerCase` to convert to lower case.

```
ResourceFunction["FromCamelCase"]["CompactSubspaceOfHausdorffSpaceIsClosed"]
(* "Compact Subspace Of Hausdorff Space Is Closed" *)
```

Answer (score 15):

```
StringReplace["CompactSubspaceOfHausdorffSpaceIsClosed", 
 u_?UpperCaseQ :> " " <> ToLowerCase[u]]

(*" compact subspace of hausdorff space is closed"*)
```

Comment: I like your answer.  It does create an extra space at the beginning so perhaps adding StringTrim would help.  Although that would remove spaces if they existed.

Comment: @MarkR That was not the original question. However that can be addressed by adding one more rule `StringReplace["CompactSub...", {RegularExpression["^\\s*[A-Z]"] :> ToLowerCase["$0"], u_?UpperCaseQ :> " " <> ToLowerCase[u]}]`. It depends what exactly is required.

Answer (score 4):

This handles acronyms and numbers properly:

```
deCamelCase[s_]:=StringRiffle@StringSplit[s,{RegularExpression["(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])"],RegularExpression["(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])"],RegularExpression["(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])"]}]
```

Based on an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java

Answer (score 4):

```
splitCamelCase = ToLowerCase @ 
   StringInsert[#, " ", StringPosition[#, _?UpperCaseQ][[2;;, 1]]] &;

splitCamelCase @ "CompactSubspaceOfHausdorffSpaceIsClosed"
```

> ```
> "compact subspace of hausdorff space is closed"
> ```

Comment: This won't work correctly with acronyms inside of the string. But has the advantage of supporting languages other than English.

Comment: Of course the proper noun "Hausdorff" should not be lower-cased, but that's a semantic issue rather than a syntactical issue that could only be addressed by some kind of dictionary look-up to identify proper nouns (and even that can be ambiguous).

Answer (score 3):

Use a Regular Expression with a positive look-behind to insert a space before each capital letter that is preceded by either a lower-case letter or a digit (that is, insert a space before each capital letter except the first)

```
StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(?<=[a-z1-9])([A-Z])"]:> " $1" ] // ToLowerCase

    (*compact subspace of hausdorff space is closed*)
```

If `str` begins with a space, or contains digits:

```
str2="  Compact1Subspace2OfHausdorffSpace3IsClosed"
StringReplace[str2, RegularExpression["(?<=[a-z1-9])([A-Z])"]:> " $1" ]//ToLowerCase

(*  compact1 subspace2 of hausdorff space3 is closed*)
```